# If I heat up a ball, is the radial temperature gradient in the middle of it going to be zero in all directions?

Tags: thermodynamics, thought-experiment

Assume I have a uniform ball, heat transfer is solely governed by the heat equation ($\dot{u} = \alpha \Delta u$). It has an initial temperature distribution solely dependent on $r$, ie $T=T(r)$, where $T(r)$.

If I start to heat my ball up from all directions uniformly, will the radial temperature gradient in the exact center be a zero?

I believe that the overall gradient, $\nabla T$ is going to be $\underline{0}$, because there is no preferential direction. That that does however mean that $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}T$ is also going to be $0$ in the middle (because it could be that $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}T$ is nonzero but constant, making the overall gradient vector zero by opposite directions cancelling each other). It would make my life much easier if $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}T$ was also $0$.

If it is zero, how do I argue for it being $0$? (and if it isn't, why it isn't?)

Comment: Nice, I had the exact same question about 3 days ago.

Comment: All directions are symmetrical so there is no preferred choice to point towards.

Comment: @Gert $\Delta$ is an alternative notation for the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

Comment: @G.Smith Really? Never came across it...

Comment: Wikipedia mentions it (see the beginning of this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). My notes also mention it, though they don't use it widely.

Comment: @Gert It’s used throughout the Wikipedia article that I linked to.

Comment: Too many g-ddamn different notations around! ;-)

Comment: (Oh yes, sorry for linking the same article after @G.Smith you linked it too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature through the ball will have zero slope in the middle.  It will not have a sharp peak or sharp minimum.  That means it has a gradient of zero in the middle.

Comment: You can arrive at this by symmetry and by assuming continuity: Because the system is spherically symmetrical, the temperature around any spherical shell will be constant. Assume that the temperature function is continuous in all its derivatives, and that demands a gradient of zero at $r=0$.  I *think* the continuity assumption is valid, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @TimWescott It is not that obvious. The symmetry argument, for example, fails with the Schrodinger's equation (incidentally very similar to the heat equation). E.g. in the hydrogen atom solution, there are angular dependence (the spherical harmonics parts) of the solution to the equation, however both the equation itself and the system have a spherical symmetry.

Comment: If the temperature distribution is symmetrical and continuous about the center, the gradient of temperature there can only be zero or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If it was heated from all sides the temperature gradient in the middle would only vanish if gravity was zero and pressure uniform.

Assuming there is gravity and you have a ball filled with air then there is going to be convection of particles inside of it as some gets warmer fast (the ones close to the edges) and some takes longer (the ones in the middle). The warm air close to the edges will expand and move upward in the balloon due to pressure gradients inside and therefore the temperature inside won't be isotropic.

Now let's assume no gravity and make the pressure inside the ball uniform and then start heating the ball equally from all sides the temperature gradient will be zero as the middle of the ball will be a stationary point (temperature minimum) in the temperature profile in any cross section of the ball. You can prove this by using symmetry.